# Timer Run Once,Not continuous

Tags: c#, timer

I apologize for the use of language translation

I want to run the timer once. Next blogger.I'm saving it to the database.

Ongoing notification..One in 4 seconds

timer1 :Enabled ,Interval :4000

MyCode:

```
        public bool InternetKontrol()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient kontrol_client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("www.google.com.tr", 80);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            label1.Text = "";
            return false;
        }                      


    }


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (InternetKontrol()==false)
        {


            NetGelenGiden ngg = new NetGelenGiden();
            ngg.GidenZaman = "Net Gitti " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString();
            ngg.GelenZaman = "";


            dat.NetGelenGidens.Add(ngg);
            dat.SaveChanges();



            notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Net Durum", "Net Gitti " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString(),ToolTipIcon.Info);
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;



            label2.Text ="Net Gitti "+ DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString();




        }
```

Comment: Where do you define the Timer object? I don't see one.

Comment: I want to work once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are defining Timer control in a Windows Forms (that's because you don't put the timer1 declaration).

At the beginning of your event timer1_Tick, disable or stop the timer:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private bool InternetKontrol() { /* your code */ }

    public bool flagInternetService = true;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newResult = InternetKontrol();
        var warn = false;
        if (flagInternetService != newResult){
            if (newResult == false) warn = true;
            flagInternetService = newResult;
        }
        if (warn)
        {
            /* your code warning */
            label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give details..Thank you

Comment: It does not work after stopping. Give me just a warning and then go on again. I get a warning once.

Comment: You can try with timer1.Enabled = false;
I put a mini complete example if you want to try in another project to isolate the problem. Maybe you are restarting the timer in another place.

Comment: I think that is what you wanted "Timer run once, not continuous".
Then there is another event/condition when your timer restart counting again.

Comment: By the way (using Google Translator):
NetGelenGiden = Net Inbound Outbound; 
Giden Zaman = Time Out; 
GelenZaman = Incoming Time

Comment: Give it a warning once. Then do not warn it often.

Comment: So you want a warning once (if there is no internet I think), and then you want to launch another warning if internet returns and then goes out again?
Maybe you need a logic, for example a flag to indicate the internet service changes

Comment: Sorry, the previous edit warn always the internet status change. I edit to warn only when change and the actual status is false.